# Unable to display Google Interstitial Ads on my iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have integrated the google AdMob interstitial ads in my iOS App using the following code:-

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)

    }

    // Google Ads

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    
    }

}
```

When I run test ads, I am able to see the interstitial ads! But, after replacing the test ID with my Interstitial Ad Unit ID, I cannot see the live interstitial ads on my iOS app. Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Thanks:)

These are the logs after running my app on my iOS Device:-

[image]

Comment: please capture logs and update in your question. Error code will give you reason of not displaying ads

Comment: @AmodGokhale I checked the logs but, there was no mention of the Google Mobile Ads SDK showing an error!

Comment: filter logs by "ad" or "error"

Comment: @AmodGokhale I have updated my answer with the crash logs!

Answer (score 2):

You must test your google ads with test id like below as per [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial).

**Interstitial Test id**

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910

Adding test id and try again.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it works fine with the test ID, but, not with my Interstital Ad Unit ID!

Comment: Which I created from my Google AdMob account!

Comment: Please be alert in debug mode you can't use your live id of AdMob. You can only update with real AdMob id at that time uploading build to appStore.

Comment: I have already uploaded my app to the app store and downloaded the app from the app store, but, still, it is not showing the Interstitial ads!

Comment: ok fine. so, please check your google AdMob account. there is some privacy violation or anything else your ad is limited from Google check it first.

Comment: I am running two apps on my same Google AdMob account, but, the ads are showing fine for the 1st app and not for this app!

Comment: there is some issue with second app in google account. where you check simulator or device ?

Comment: I have downloaded the app from the app store and checked it In my iOS Device

Comment: And I am even running the app in my iOS Device from Xcode to check for the crash logs which I have provided above in my question!

Comment: In my google Ad mob account, it shows 80 requests but, no impressions for this app!

Comment: In google account payment information is already setup or not 
?

Comment: Yes, the payment information has already been set-up

Comment: After setup payment information wait 24 hr than after ads are loading with real ID

Comment: The payment information was set-up 4 months ago!

Comment: when your app is live on appstore ?

Comment: It was live on the app store Today!

Comment: already add your live app link  in google AdMob account ?

Comment: NO the app is not linked with the app store yet!

Comment: As it is not displaying my app when I search in google adMob

Comment: so please wait for linked your app.

Comment: I am giving you an upvote for this answer:)

Comment: For the app that shows ads. This is also an IOS app and it is linked in admob dashboard?